# Sonar scanner for MSBuild ERROR: Failed to parse file [<path-to-file>l-debug.js] at line 55623: Unexpected token (

Tags: javascript, msbuild, sonarqube, bamboo, sonarqube-scan

Trying to run sonarqube scan on a project and I am getting "Execution Success" as sonarqube result but the bamboo task result is in "Failure" state due to the below error:

```
ERROR: Failed to parse file [<path-to-file>l-debug.js] at line 55623: Unexpected token (
ERROR: Failed to parse file [<path-to-file>l3gm-debug.js] at line 55373: Unexpected token (
```

for example *l-debug.js* file, line 55623 starts with "(color:" :

```
        var textStyle = new ol.style.Text({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                /** @type {ol.Color} */
                (color: "color" in object ? object["color"] : ol.format.KML.DEFAULT_COLOR_),
            }),
            /** @type {number|undefined} */
            (scale: object["scale"]),
        });
```

*Currently using:*

SonarQube version: **7.9.5**

Sonar Scanner version: **sonar-scanner-msbuild-5.0.4.24009-net46**

I am sure, by disabling ***Fail build when SonarQube reports analysis errors*** in bamboo job will solve the problem but we don't want to see false success.

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to SonarQube 8.9.x version fixed this issue.